# PayPal CUSTOMER.DISPUTE.CREATED webhook event not firing in live

Tags: paypal, webhooks

I have created PayPal webhooks for CUSTOMER.DISPUTE.CREATED, CUSTOMER.DISPUTE.RESOLVED and RISK.DISPUTE.CREATED (deprecated, but after the first two didn't work I figured hey, why not...) in an app on the account I am trying to receive webhook event notifications for.  I created them a week ago, and have had several disputes occur that I can view and download in the Resolution Center since the webhooks were added.  Under REST Apps->Live Webhooks it shows that I am subscribed to these events, but I have not received anything at my callback url, and under Dashboard->Live->Webhook Events it says that I do not have any events for the selected application.  The Webhook Simulator sends these events fine in Sandbox.  Is there an issue with these webhooks that anyone knows about?

Comment: I have the same problem. It might be a Paypal unreleased feature as of today? Linked discussion: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/Dispute-Webhook-Events-not-firing/td-p/1197739